# AWS Lambda different date result using moment JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

My time zone is GMT+8. and my AWS region is Singapore (ap-southeast-1)
My concern is they have different results when calculating dates, when i deployed my code in aws/lambda, i got different result from my local machine. what I want to achieve or my goal is that the AWS Lambda will have a same result like in my local

my local result: 2023-04-05T16:00:00.000Z

lambda result: 2023-04-06T00:00:00.000Z

code:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const dateToday = new Date();

const today = dateToday.toLocaleDateString();

const accumulatedDate = moment.utc(new Date(today)).add(118, 'days').toISOString();

console.log(accumulatedDate);
```

Comment: As an aside, please use https://day.js.org/ - as the moment library is no longer maintained.

Comment: Hi @painotpi, thankyou for this but do you think that would solve my problem when im going to use dayjs? I'm just curious as Im not aware on dayjs as well. thanks for positive answer

Comment: Nah, I don't know if it'll make a difference, hence I posted it as a suggestion. Your code seems fine to me and I can't seem to figure out what could be going wrong since you're converting to UTC (and ISO).

Comment: Keep in mind, lambda functions use [UTC timezone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime). If you're in GMT+8 though, I'm not sure why your local date is _before_ the lambda's date.

Answer (score 0):

The toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language-sensitive representation of the date portion of the specified date in the user agent's timezone.

I think the issue is that you are converting your local timestamp to be represented as UTC, rather than just using UTC.

The toUTCString() method converts a date to a string, interpreting it in the UTC time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this result because `toLocaleDateString()` truncates the time. But "truncate the time" is inherently a timezone-sensitive operation. If you convert a date+time to a date, you need to decide which time zone's midnight you're going to use to truncate the time.

For example, assume a time like `2000-01-01T04:00Z`.  In New York (UTC-5), `toLocaleDateString('en-US')` would return `'12/31/1999'` (which, when converted to UTC, is `1999-12-31T05:00Z`). While in London it'd return `'2000-01-01'` (which, when converted to UTC, is `2000-01-01T00:00Z`).

If you want to get the same result on your local machine as on the server, then you'll need to use the same time zone in both places. Which time zone you use depends on the use cases of your app. For example, if you want to report on "Sales made yesterday at our store in Shanghai" then you'll probably want to use the `Asia/Shanghai` time zone. If you are writing to a log file, then you'll probably want to use UTC. If you're summarizing revenue for a multinational corporation headquartered in Marseille, then you'll probably want to use `Europe/Paris`. And so on.

BTW, instead of moment.js. you may want to look at [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/), which is a new JavaScript built-in object that will be shipping in browsers and Node.js soon, likely within the next year or so. Temporal is the successor API to JavaScript's venerable `Date` object, and it has first-class support for time zones and date/time arithmetic. There are [Temporal polyfills](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills) available now. (Full disclosure: for the last few years I helped to lead the team that designed the Temporal API.)

Using Temporal, your code could look something like this:

```js
import { Temporal } from '@js-temporal/polyfill';

// If you want to use UTC
const today = Temporal.Now.plainDateISO('UTC'); // 2022-12-14
const accumulatedDate = today.add({ days: 118 }).toString(); // 2023-04-11

// If you want to use a specific time zone
const today = Temporal.Now.plainDateISO('Asia/Singapore'); // 2022-12-15
const accumulatedDate = today.add({ days: 118 }).toString(); // 2023-04-12
```